# Linux install nightmare, now video seems to be broken even during installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, fedora, uefi

It's a long story but I can't keep these details to myself because I have no clue what's going on, it's pretty weird.

I have two hard drives. One had windows, and the other one had nothing, it was brand new. So I installed Ubuntu 13.10 just fine, except for the USB keyboard which would stop working as soon as I pressed ctrl+C trying to copy text (worked just fine on Windows, so it was weird). After a lot of suffering I tried plugging it into different USB ports and somehow it started working fine. Everything was perfect now, but I tried installing the NVIDIA drivers and everything went to hell. I knew it could happen, but I tried anyway because the worst case scenario would be that I would have to reinstall, which wasn't a problem since it was a fresh install anyway and I had time.

The problem is I can't install it correctly anymore! The graphics in the installer are messed up, the screen doesn't refresh until I move the mouse, which leaves horrible trails all over the screen. And it only refreshes the places where I hovered over. I decided I could withstand the installation if at least the fresh install worked fine after that. But no, the fresh install sucks too. The keyboard is slow, the mouse leaves trails, etc.

I thought maybe something was being stored in the boot sector of that disc or whatever. So I deleted the partitions and ran `dd if=/dev/zero bs=512 count=1 of=/dev/sda` just in case. Didn't fix the problem.

I also downloaded boot-repair and burned a DVD, but after booting and choosing normal/fail-safe and loading for a few seconds it shows a black screen.

My only hope is that this issue is related to BIOS or UEFI (does that even make sense?), which is showing old entries of previous OSs. I have no clue how to edit the UEFI though. The motherboard's DVD didn't help.

Other OS I tried: Fedora 20, black screen.

I also tried connecting only 1 hard drive, tried with both. Didn't work.

Windows 7 still works perfectly, so it's not the VGA. The VGA doesn't store any data, right?

What can I do?

Comment: How did you install the Nvidia driver?!

Comment: The best I can work out may be something related to a soft switch that was activated somehow by ubuntu's faulty drivers, have you tried restoring your card's settings from windows? I've never heard anything like this.